# Scala for comprehension result of map operation is coming as Int

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

Please look at the below code,

`

```
val d= for{
      t <- db.getSomething()
      ids <- t.map(_.id).toSeq
      histo <- fetchOtherRelatedDetails(ids)
    } yield histo
```

`

Here, db.getSomething is returning a Future[Seq[SomeObject]], So I am trying to fetch the object and then map their IDs into a list and then wanted to call another function which will process the ids to fetch result in Future. TYhe problem with compiler is it is taking the `ids` as Int which is supposed to be `Seq[Int]`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a first glance, you have a type mismatch in the for-comprehension:

```
for {
  t <- db.getSomething()
  ids <- t.map(_.id).toSeq
  histo <- fetchOtherRelatedDetails(ids)
} yield histo
```

this desugars to

```
db.getSomething().flatMap { t =>
  t.map(_.id).toSeq.flatMap { ids =>
//^_______________________^ 
// the return type of this expression is Seq[A], but Future[A] is expected
    fetchOtherRelatedDetails(ids).map(histo => histo)
  }
}
```

As noted inline, you can't return a `Seq` where a `Future` is expected. In other terms, all the expression on the right of a `<-` must have a common "container" (`Future` in this case) for the for-comprehension to typecheck.

In this specific case, you can fix it with an assignment instead of a `flatMap` (`<-`)

```
for {
  t <- db.getSomething()
  ids = t.map(_.id).toSeq
  histo <- fetchOtherRelatedDetails(ids)
} yield histo
```